# How do I collect many pieces stored in html files into one template in Django?

Tags: python, django

Supposing I have a page to display that consists of several pieces like this:

```
<!-- result page -->
<div>
    <b>1st piece</b>
</div>
<div>
    <b>2nd piece</b>
</div>
<div>
    <b>3rd piece</b>
</div>
```

I want to keep each piece in a separate html-file:

```
<!-- piece1.html -->
<b>1st piece</b>

<!-- piece2.html -->
<b>2nd piece</b>

<!-- piece3.html -->
<b>3rd piece</b>
```

And add them into a base template using Django templates:

```
<!-- base.html -->
<div>
    {% block piece1 %}... import piece1.html ...{% endblock %}
</div>
<div>
    {% block piece2 %}... import piece2.html ...{% endblock %}
</div>
<div>
    {% block piece3 %}... import piece3.html ...{% endblock %}
</div>
```

How do I manage `base.html` to make it import all pieces by their names in Django? Or maybe there's a different approach to do it easily?

In my project I'm going to use a complicated structure of pieces and big size for each one. This is why I want to keep each piece in a separate html-file.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#include

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `include` tag.

```
{% include 'piece1.html' %}
{% include 'piece2.html' %}
```